# is it possible to avoid a creation of defaut /healthz readinessProbe on GKE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I want to avoid creation of default `/healthz` readinessProbe during creation of ingress on GKE.
i just want to see what I defined in Deployment manifest of a service.

---

**Here is my ingress manifest file:**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
  namespace: ns
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "static-ip"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /auth/*
            backend:
              serviceName: auth
              servicePort: 3002
          - path: /usermanagement/*
            backend:
              serviceName: auth
              servicePort: 3002
```

**Here is my deployment of auth service:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: ns
  name: auth
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: <path>
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 3002
              protocol: TCP
          readinessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            httpGet:
              path: /auth/health
              port: 3002
```

So i assumed that i will have only one health check `/auth/health`. But GKE creates additional health check `/healthz`

Screenshot of health checks page:

[image]

Comment: readinessProbe is added to your deployment. If you want you can remove it before deploying the manifest. You need to provide more details about the manifest you want to use and steps you are taking.

Comment: @Crou thanks, I've updated question.

Comment: Where are you getting the health check page from? The ports you showed do not match your `Deployment`.

Comment: compute engine -> health checks.
but auth/health works well. despite of different ports... ports also confusing me.

Comment: You can try clicking at the name under `In use by` which will tell you what for was it created. It's weird because nothing seems to match your health checks page as ports are way different.